# Clicking on element (with offset)

Tags: javascript

Please help in the implementation of the following problem.
Need to perform a click on a particular element, but with an offset.

If i use a standard click - **element.click()**, then click occurs in the upper left corner of the element:

[image: [image #1]]

But i need to do click here:

[image: [image #2]]

Can I perform a click on an **element + offset**?
Something like this -

```
element.click().offset('top: 32, left: 32')
```

p.s. Ssory for my english.

Answer (score 3):

- I see you using `element.click()` and assume you are using jQuery. What you want is not possible with jQuery, it can't set offset parameters to the event, you have to use native javascript.
- A click-event-object has two pairs of parameters inside: `clientX / clientY` and `pageX / pageY`. Both describe the position of the mousepointer when the click occurs.
- The position is **relative to the document, not to the element**. A standard click has `clientX: 0, clientY: 0` so it occurs in the upper left corner of the document, not of the element.
- If you want to click on an element, you have to set `clientX / clientY` to the **position of the element relative to the document**. You find elements position with `.getBoundingClientRect()`.
- The positions in the Rect `.left / .top` are the coordinates of elements topLeft corner. Using them inside the event clicks on its topLeft corner.
- Now you can add an offset to the coordinates. Inside the Rect you find also the `width / height` of the element. If you add the half of them to `x, y` you get coordinates of elements center. Using that in the event performs a click at its center.

---

```
function clickOnElem(elem, offsetX, offsetY) {
    var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),
        posX = rect.left, posY = rect.top; // get elems coordinates
    // calculate position of click
    if (typeof offsetX == 'number') posX += offsetX;
    else if (offsetX == 'center') {
        posX += rect.width / 2;
        if (offsetY == null) posY += rect.height / 2;
    }
    if (typeof offsetY == 'number') posY += offsetY;
    // create event-object with calculated position
    var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, clientX: posX, clientY: posY});    
    elem.dispatchEvent(evt); // trigger the event on elem
}
```

You use it as follows;

```
var el = document.getElementById("myElem");
clickOnElem(el); // clicks on topLeft corner
clickOnElem(el, 'center'); // clicks on elements center
clickOnElem(el, 30, 40); // clicks inside element, 30px from left and 40px from top
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way to do it:

```js
function func(){
alert("Circle clicked!")
}
```

```css
div{
  border-radius: 100000px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div onClick="func()"></div>
```